# Is it Possible to Block SMS outgoing in iPhone?

Tags: iphone

How to Block the SMS Outgoing service from iPhone within application.

Comment: The public API won't let you do it.

Comment: Why would you want to block SMS service?

Comment: Are you talking about App Store apps or something on the Enterprise side? If it's the latter, I'd suggest looking at the options available for iPhone Configuration files and Mobile Device Management. These allow you to toggle many iOS features that wouldn't normally be toggle-able in the UI or through APIs.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible if you want your app accepted into Apple's app store, the outgoing SMS is definitely a private API.